# Upper bound on $|\{ t \in [n]: gcd(t,n) =j \}|$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let us fix a divisor $j$ of $n$. Consider the set of integers $t \in \{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ such that the greatest common divisor of $t$ and $n$ is $j$. I want to see if there is an upper bound on the size of such set (the bound may or may not depend on $j$). That is, I want an upper bound on

$$
|\{ t \in [n]: \gcd(t,n)= j\}|.
$$

I wonder if anything like this is known.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The size of the set $t$ you are describing is given by $\phi\left(\frac{n}{j}\right)$, so:
$$\left|\left\{ t\in\left[n\right]:\gcd\left(t,n\right)=j\right\} \right|=\phi\left(\frac{n}{j}\right)$$
where $\phi$ is Euler's totient function. This gives us the upper bound:
$$\left|\left\{ t\in\left[n\right]:\gcd\left(t,n\right)=j\right\} \right|\leq\frac{n}{j}-1$$